# Javascript Loop not displaying more than 1 instance of the data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having issues with some code where it's not displaying more than 1 instance of the data.

Here is the full data and code:

The Data:

```
var json = [
{
    "main": [
        {
            "id": "7561",
            "secid": "5",
            "carid": "653",
            "phaseId": "0",
            "title": "idea 2",
            "text": "<p>dfggfd</p>",
            "created": "2016-05-19 10:52:37",
            "user": {
                "id": "24793",
                "username": "myUsername",
                "firstName": "myName",
                "lastName": "mySurname",
                "bio": "",
                "town": "London",
                "country": "United Kingdom",
                "avatar": "na",
                "confirmed": true,
                "hasEml": true,
                "haspsword": true,
                "hEV": true,
                "hasTermsAgreed": false,
                "hasCommunityTermsAgreed": true,
                "profileQuestionAns": {
                    "userfield_14": {
                        "id": 6223,
                        "user": 24793,
                        "userfield": 14,
                        "data": "fdszgsfdgsd"
                    },
                    "userfield_15": {
                        "id": 6224,
                        "user": 24793,
                        "userfield": 15,
                        "data": "Blah"
                    }
                },
                "usertype": "2",
                "ha": true,
                "language": null,
                "walkthroughpsed": "1",
                "registerEmlSent": false,
                "hasCompletedOnBoarding": true
            },
            "co": [],
            "vtingData": {
                "values": {
                    "1": "1"
                },
                "totalVTs": "1",
                "score": "1",
                "type": "up",
                "mostpopVT": "1",
                "userVT": 0,
                "isClosed": 0
            },
            "fileData": [],
            "cmtCount": 0,
            "canBeVTd": true,
            "mlestId": "53",
            "mlestStatus": 0,
            "mlestTimeout": 0,
            "pstfields": [],
            "modLabel": null,
            "tags": [],
            "modStatus": "0"
        },
        {
            "id": "7560",
            "secid": "5",
            "carid": "653",
            "phaseId": "0",
            "title": "idea 1",
            "text": "<p>adsfasdf</p>",
            "created": "2016-05-19 10:33:48",
            "user": {
                "id": "24787",
                "username": "Ar_2",
                "firstName": "myName",
                "lastName": "mySurname",
                "bio": "",
                "town": "London",
                "country": "United Kingdom",
                "avatar": "sdffds",
                "confirmed": true,
                "hasEml": true,
                "haspsword": true,
                "hEV": true,
                "hasTermsAgreed": false,
                "hasCommunityTermsAgreed": true,
                "profileQuestionAns": {
                    "userfield_14": {
                        "id": 6208,
                        "user": 24787,
                        "userfield": 14,
                        "data": "aDASDASD"
                    },
                    "userfield_15": {
                        "id": 6209,
                        "user": 24787,
                        "userfield": 15,
                        "data": "Blah"
                    }
                },
                "usertype": "2",
                "ha": true,
                "language": null,
                "walkthroughpsed": "1",
                "registerEmlSent": false,
                "hasCompletedOnBoarding": true
            },
            "co": [],
            "vtingData": {
                "values": {
                    "1": "2"
                },
                "totalVTs": "2",
                "score": "2",
                "type": "up",
                "mostpopVT": "1",
                "userVT": 0,
                "isClosed": 0
            },
            "fileData": [],
            "cmtCount": 0,
            "canBeVTd": true,
            "mlestId": "53",
            "mlestStatus": 0,
            "mlestTimeout": 0,
            "pstfields": [],
            "modLabel": null,
            "tags": [],
            "modStatus": "0"
        }
    ]
}];
```

The Javascript Code:

```
var tr;
    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
        var obj = json[i];
        tr = $('<tr/>');
        tr.append("<td>" + json[i]['main'][i].id + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + json[i]['main'][i]['user'].username + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + json[i]['main'][i].carid + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + json[i]['main'][i]['user'].firstName + " " + json[i]['ideas'][i]['user'].lastName + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + json[i]['main'][i].id + "</td>");
        $('table').append(tr);

    }


});
```

How can I make it display all instances?

Comment: `json` is an array with *one* element. (And as an aside, it's not JSON.) Perhaps you want to loop over the `json[0].main` array rather than the `json` array?

Comment: `json` is not JSON. But this another issue.

Comment: You can try first parsing it and then using json.main.length instead of json.length

Comment: You overwrite `obj` on each iteration and never do anything with it. What's the purpose of that variable?

Comment: OK, if we forget the JSON part, how can I get it to loop all entries, as it's only looping 1. The code works and it reads and appends the data but only 1.

Comment: As nnnnnn already explained, you only have one entry!

Comment: There's actually 2 entries and it's valid json...I've tested it here: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is because you are not correctly accessing the object. `json` is an array which contains only a single item. Instead you need to loop through through the `json[0].main` array, like this:

```
var tr;
for (var i = 0; i < json[0].main.length; i++) {
    var obj = json[0].main[i];
    tr = $('<tr/>');
    tr.append("<td>" + obj.id + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td>" + obj.user.username + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td>" + obj.carid + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td>" + obj.user.firstName + " " + obj.user.lastName + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td>" + obj.id + "</td>");
    $('table').append(tr);
}
```

**Working example:**

```js
var json = [{
    "main": [{
        "id": "7561",
        "secid": "5",
        "carid": "653",
        "phaseId": "0",
        "title": "idea 2",
        "text": "<p>dfggfd</p>",
        "created": "2016-05-19 10:52:37",
        "user": {
            "id": "24793",
            "username": "myUsername",
            "firstName": "myName",
            "lastName": "mySurname",
            "bio": "",
            "town": "London",
            "country": "United Kingdom",
            "avatar": "na",
            "confirmed": true,
            "hasEml": true,
            "haspsword": true,
            "hEV": true,
            "hasTermsAgreed": false,
            "hasCommunityTermsAgreed": true,
            "profileQuestionAns": {
                "userfield_14": {
                    "id": 6223,
                    "user": 24793,
                    "userfield": 14,
                    "data": "fdszgsfdgsd"
                },
                "userfield_15": {
                    "id": 6224,
                    "user": 24793,
                    "userfield": 15,
                    "data": "Blah"
                }
            },
            "usertype": "2",
            "ha": true,
            "language": null,
            "walkthroughpsed": "1",
            "registerEmlSent": false,
            "hasCompletedOnBoarding": true
        },
        "co": [],
        "vtingData": {
            "values": {
                "1": "1"
            },
            "totalVTs": "1",
            "score": "1",
            "type": "up",
            "mostpopVT": "1",
            "userVT": 0,
            "isClosed": 0
        },
        "fileData": [],
        "cmtCount": 0,
        "canBeVTd": true,
        "mlestId": "53",
        "mlestStatus": 0,
        "mlestTimeout": 0,
        "pstfields": [],
        "modLabel": null,
        "tags": [],
        "modStatus": "0"
    }, {
        "id": "7560",
        "secid": "5",
        "carid": "653",
        "phaseId": "0",
        "title": "idea 1",
        "text": "<p>adsfasdf</p>",
        "created": "2016-05-19 10:33:48",
        "user": {
            "id": "24787",
            "username": "Ar_2",
            "firstName": "myName",
            "lastName": "mySurname",
            "bio": "",
            "town": "London",
            "country": "United Kingdom",
            "avatar": "sdffds",
            "confirmed": true,
            "hasEml": true,
            "haspsword": true,
            "hEV": true,
            "hasTermsAgreed": false,
            "hasCommunityTermsAgreed": true,
            "profileQuestionAns": {
                "userfield_14": {
                    "id": 6208,
                    "user": 24787,
                    "userfield": 14,
                    "data": "aDASDASD"
                },
                "userfield_15": {
                    "id": 6209,
                    "user": 24787,
                    "userfield": 15,
                    "data": "Blah"
                }
            },
            "usertype": "2",
            "ha": true,
            "language": null,
            "walkthroughpsed": "1",
            "registerEmlSent": false,
            "hasCompletedOnBoarding": true
        },
        "co": [],
        "vtingData": {
            "values": {
                "1": "2"
            },
            "totalVTs": "2",
            "score": "2",
            "type": "up",
            "mostpopVT": "1",
            "userVT": 0,
            "isClosed": 0
        },
        "fileData": [],
        "cmtCount": 0,
        "canBeVTd": true,
        "mlestId": "53",
        "mlestStatus": 0,
        "mlestTimeout": 0,
        "pstfields": [],
        "modLabel": null,
        "tags": [],
        "modStatus": "0"
    }]
}];

var tr;
for (var i = 0; i < json[0].main.length; i++) {
    var obj = json[0].main[i];
    tr = $('<tr/>');
    tr.append("<td>" + obj.id + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td>" + obj.user.username + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td>" + obj.carid + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td>" + obj.user.firstName + " " + obj.user.lastName + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td>" + obj.id + "</td>");
    $('table').append(tr);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

After throwing your Data into a formatter, it becomes obvious that your dataset only contains one element, namely "main".
Therefore, `json.length` equals 1 and your loop only iterates once.

You may want to iterate over the items in main instead.

Answer (score 0):

According to the way your `json` object is built, you need this to loop through the array:

```
for (var i = 0; i < json[0][main].length; i++) {
  record = json[0][main][i];
  doSomethingWith(record)
}
```

Your json object first 'level' is an array with 1 item: `main`. Inside `main` is the array with data you want to loop through.

Answer (score 0):

`json` is an array of object. So `json[0].main` will return the `main` array. Use `forEach` to loop through it

```
var _getMain= json[0].main;
console.log(json[0])
var tr;
_getMain.forEach(function(item){
  tr = $('<tr/>');
        tr.append("<td>" + item.id + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + item.user.username + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + item.carid + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + item.user.firstName + " " + item.user.lastName + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + item.id + "</td>");
        $('#table').append(tr);

})
```

Note: I could not find any key by `ideas`. Not sure how you this snippet will work

```
json[i]['ideas'][i]['user'].lastName
```

Also manipulating DOM is costly process. Instead try to create the DOM and append all at once

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/62k4081j/2/)